# How to migrate j2ee application into spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to migrate my Servlet web application into spring boot application

I want the step to migrate the project fromj2ee project into spring bott

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: what migrate my servelt project into spring boot